# Como comparar duas listas encadeadas em C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Galera estou com problema nessa questão:

-Tenho que comparar duas listas encadeadas e retornar 1 se forem iguais ou 0 se não forem.

A função está assim e não consigo progredir:

```
  struct Node
  {
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
 }





 int CompareLists(Node *headA, Node* headB) 
 { 
  /*se as duas forem vazias*/
   if(headA->next==NULL && headB->next==NULL) 
  { 
   return 1; 
   } 
   if(headA->next==NULL || headB->next==NULL) 
   { 
   return 0; 
   }  
   while(headA->next!=NULL && headB->next!=NULL) 
   { 
   if(headA->data=!headB->data) 
   { 
   return 0; 
   }else{ 
   return 1; 
   } 
   headA=headA->next; 
   headB=headB->next; 

   } 
   }
```

Acho que o problema está em percorrer a lista (**headA=headA->next**), mas não sei como fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por igual, você define o mesmo conteúdo na mesma ordem?

Comment: Não atualize o código da pergunta com código de respostas, pois isso invalida quaisquer respostas dadas até ao momento, e não é a forma como o StackOverflow funciona.

Comment: @Isac já consegui muito obrigado. Desculpa pelo incomodo.

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar listas é necessário percorrer as listas até chegar a uma conclusão.
Esse while só irá acabar quando pelo menos uma delas chegar a NULL (que vai ser testado no while) logo:

```
while(headA->next != NULL && headB->next != NULL){
    ...
    headA = headA->next;
    headB = headB->next;
}
```

Essas são as últimas linhas, ou seja, quando headA estiver na penúltima estrutura (ou seja, headA->next seja NULL), o while não será realizado pois
headA atingiu a penúltima e headB não:

```
while(0 && 1) => while(0)
```

Ou seja, acabou a iteração.
Quando acaba a iteração, a função não dá resposta, simplesmente sai pois as únicas saídas que a função tem são os if's

```
int CompareLists(Node *headA, Node* headB) 
{ 
   /*se as duas forem vazias*/
   if(headA->next==NULL && headB->next==NULL) 
   { 
       return 1; 
   } 
   if(headA->next==NULL || headB->next==NULL) 
   { 
       return 0; 
   }  
   while(headA->next!=NULL && headB->next!=NULL) 
   { 
       if(headA->data=!headB->data) 
       { 
           return 0; 
       }else{ 
           return 1; 
       } 
       headA=headA->next; 
       headB=headB->next; 

   } 
}
```

Comment: Troquei de lugar o return 1 e pus depois da { do while  e tirei o else, porém, a saída ta diferente do esperado. Está com a saída 1 1 1 1 e tem que retornar 1 0 0 0 segundo o que está no exercício.

Comment: `while` com `return` no `if` e no `else` ? O seu else não seria antes fora do `while` ? E o `=!` não seria `!=`  ?

Comment: o que o @Isac disse é verdade, =! não existe... ou é == ! ou é !=
Na edição meti a minha forma de testar se 2 listas são iguais. Se quiser testar a minha forma a ver se está bem faça-o. Caso esteja correta leia e perceba. Alguma coisa mande mensagem para mim que eu ajudo.
Eu não tenho muita experiência com listas, mas farei o meu melhor para o ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação pessoal, mas continua dando erro. Será que falta alguma condição? Vou editar o código ai em cima

Comment: @YODA a primeira iteração (dentro do while) vai dar 1 devido ao else

Comment: @DarkGV mudei agora o código da uma olhada ai em cima.

Comment: @YODA meta no fim da função return 1 e teste sff

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct No
{
    int nConteudo;
    struct No *prox;
}TNo;
 

typedef TNo* TLista;

void liberar_memoria(TLista p);

void verificaPar(TLista p1, TLista p2);

void mostraLista(TLista p1, TLista p2);
 
int main(void)
{
    TLista pNo1 = NULL;
    TLista pNo2 = NULL;
    TLista pNo3 = NULL;
    
    TLista pNo4 = NULL;
    TLista pNo5 = NULL;
    TLista pNo6 = NULL;
     
    
    pNo1 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo1->nConteudo = 110;
     
    pNo2 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo2->nConteudo = 210;
     
    pNo3 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo3->nConteudo = 310;
    
    
    pNo4 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo4->nConteudo = 110;
     
    pNo5 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo5->nConteudo = 210;
     
    pNo6 = (TLista) malloc(sizeof(TLista));
    pNo6->nConteudo = 310;
    
    pNo1->prox = pNo2;
    pNo2->prox = pNo3;  
    pNo3->prox = NULL;
    
    pNo4->prox = pNo5;
    pNo5->prox = pNo6;  
    pNo6->prox = NULL;
     
    mostraLista(pNo1,pNo4);
     
    verificaPar(pNo1, pNo4);
    
    liberar_memoria(pNo1);
    liberar_memoria(pNo4);
  
    return 0;
}

void liberar_memoria(TLista p)
{
    TLista atual = p;

    while (atual != NULL)
    {
        TLista proximo = atual->prox;

        free(atual);

        atual = proximo;
    }
}

void mostraLista(TLista p1, TLista p2)
{
    TLista i,j;
    printf("\nMostrando a lista:\n"); 

    if((p1)&&(p2))

    for (i=p1,j=p2; p1!=NULL;p2=p2->prox,p1=p1->prox)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t", i->nConteudo); printf("- %d\n", j->nConteudo);

        i=i->prox;  j=j->prox;        
    }

    else

    printf("Lista vazia.");

    printf("\n\n"); 
}

void verificaPar(TLista p1, TLista p2)
{
    TLista i,j, cont=0;
    
    if((p1)&&(p2))
    {
        for (i=p1,j=p2; p1!=NULL;p2=p2->prox,p1=p1->prox)
        {
            if (i->nConteudo!=j->nConteudo)
            {
                printf("NAO SAO IGUAIS - LISTAS DIFERENTES!\n");
                    cont=0;
                        break;
            }
            else 
            {
                cont++;
            }
            
            i=i->prox;
            
            j=j->prox;          
        }
            if (cont)
            {
                printf("AS LISTAS SAO IDENTICAS\n");
            }
    }    
    
    else
        
    printf("LISTAS IDENTICAS PORQUE AMBAS SAO VAZIAS.");
}
```